# Jenkins job triggered by commit on specific stream in RTC

Tags: jenkins, build, triggers, pipeline, rational-team-concert

I would like my jenkins job to activate as soon as I commit to a specific stream on RTC (or my workspace). Currently I can do this on any commit I do on RTC using the "Build Trigger -> section
Poll the source code management system "but I can only specify the polling time, not the stream or the rtc workspace to monitor.
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Jenkins job to be triggered by new commits on a repository workspace, or delivered to a stream:

- The [Build Definition](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/elm/6.0?topic=results-creating-build-definitions) uses a schedule indeed:

> To set up a continuous integration build, set the build schedule to run at an interval, such as every 5 minutes, and ensure that the Build only if there are changes accepted option is selected.
> If no changes are accepted when the scheduled build runs, the build is deleted.

- the monitored repo workspace or stream is set as a target to the Build Definition workspace, as shown here

That means:

- the build definition has its own repository workspace, which will accept changes from the target workspace/stream every 5 minutes
- as soon as new commits are accepted by the build definition workspace, the specified Jenkins job is called.